# Oracle AWR shows missing stats for SQL ID as top elapsed statement

Tags: oracle, awr

Why SQL ID has null number of executions and elapsed time / execution in AWR report. SQL ID is among top elapsed command on AWR but no details stats whoing time / execution. Would it be because shared pool got flushed or what else can cause this?

Answer (score 3):

I could think of eviction from shared pool, like your guess, or the statement running with `statistics_level=basic`. The `statistics_level` can be dynamically set on a per-session basis.

> Setting the STATISTICS_LEVEL parameter
>   to BASIC disables the collection of
>   many of the important statistics
>   required by Oracle Database features
>   and functionality, including:
>
> ```
> *
>
>   Automatic Workload Repository (AWR) Snapshots
> ```